# Regex not matching the first occurence of my string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In this url:

```
 http://example.com/SearchResult-Empty.html?caty[]=12345&caty[]=45678
```

I am trying to use the following regex to grab the first occurence of caty which should be "12345".  However, instead, the regex below is giving me the final occurrence 45678.  I tried using the "?" limiter to make it non-greedy per other stack overflow questions, but it isn't working.  How can I do this?

```
 ^SearchResult(?:.*)(caty)(?:.*)\=([0-9]+)\&?$
```

Comment: @Ghost: Sorry I was a bit brain dead... Shouldn't have said this was PHP.  It's actually htaccess...

Comment: oh okay, i never guessed its context was on htaccess

Comment: `SearchResult(?:.*?)(caty)(?:.*?)\=([0-9]+)\&?` should work just fine

Comment: Nope @vihan1086 still same thing: https://regex101.com/r/lC5rU7/1

Comment: @CRAIG seems like the `^` and `$` is messing you up: `SearchResult(?:.*?)(caty)(?:.*?)\=([0-9]+)\&?`  https://regex101.com/r/lC5rU7/2

Comment: There you go @vihan1086.  You want to make that an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, two things are messing you up:

- The anchors `^` and `$` seem to be forcing the regex to produce bad matches
- You are using greedy `.*` instead of non-greedy `.*?`

```
SearchResult(?:.*?)(caty)(?:.*?)\=([0-9]+)\&?
```

Should do the job

Comment: Thanks for the extra details on the answer @vihan1086! :)

Comment: @CRAIG No problem :)  the `$` basically *reverses* the effect of the non-greedy option making the regex engine decide whether to listen to the non-greedy to the `$`

Answer (score 1):

```
^SearchResult(?:.*)(caty)(?:.*)\=([0-9]+)\&?$
                ^^
```

`.*` is greedy matching, meaning that it will go the the *last* occurrence of `caty` rather than the first. You could check that by providing *three* `caty`'s in the input string and it will then skip the first *two.*

`.*?` makes it non-greedy (aka *reluctant*), which will consume as little as possible to make a match - stopping at the *first* occurrence of `caty`.

Comment: Right @paxdiablo but if I add a question mark afterwards

`^SearchResult(?:.*?)(caty)(?:.*?)\=([0-9]+)\&?$`

to make it non-greedy, it doesn't make a difference?